# Find a branch of particular commit and checkout to it

Tags: ruby, git, rugged

How could I easily find a branch with a particular commit and checkout to it with rugged so that I won't end with 'detached HEAD' state?

Step by step I'd like to:

- Clone repository
- `repo.lookup commithash` to return catch exception and exit if `Rugged::OdbError: Object not found` happens
- find a branch containing given commit hash
- checkout to that branch

Comment: And as you implemented the steps you outlined in your question, what have you observed?

Comment: I have no idea how to do the third step. Checking out  a commit with force strategy leaves me in detached HEAD state which I would like to avoid

Comment: What do you mean by that third step? Do you know that you have a barnch at a particular commit and would like to find it? If you checkout a commit, you *have* to detach HEAD. If you want to checkout a branch, you must pass specify the branch/ref.

Comment: I would like to do something like: 

git branch --contains <commithasg>
* devel
  master
  release-branch

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but in my case was when I was trying to run a script on CircleCi, so to avoid the error you should run `[[ ! -s \"$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/shallow\" ]] || git fetch --unshallow`, maybe in your case you just should run just `git fetch --unshallow` and then run the task that you want.